# SharePoint 2010 as Web CMS - anyone any links?

Tags: content-management-system, sharepoint-2010

Mostly interested in how to hide the SharePoint "particulars". For example whether to use the base site as "Wiki" and in this case - how to hide the "SitePages" folder and other SharePoint specifics.

And links to any pages / Documents helping there ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're looking for information on SharePoint "branding", i.e. making SharePoint not look like SharePoint.

Here are some links:

- http://branding-sharepoint.com - a SharePoint designer's blog, with links to example sites.
- http://www.wasserstudios.com/what/default.aspx - from that page, here's a site done in SharePoint
- http://www.heathersolomon.com/Blog/ - another SharePoint designer
- http://startermasterpages.codeplex.com - here's some code to get you started
- http://www.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-0470584645.html - here's an upcoming book on the subject
- http://sharepointbootcamp.com - and if your budget allows, here is some training on SharePoint branding.

It's not a simple task. These references and some additional searching on "SharePoint branding" should help you determine if it's what you want to do, and if so, get started.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the product, but I've found this. Maybe it can help you in some way: http://sharepointcanvas.com/spc/

I'm linking this because you've said hide and not disable.